# How to use stored procedure to add mutiple locations to one customer?

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, indexing

I have trouble on how to use stored procedure to add multiple locations to one customer. Below are my tables, I am using indexing to help me can add multiple locations to one customer, but should I

```
SELECT @intLocationIndex = MAX(intLocationIndex) +1
```

too?

```
CREATE TABLE TCustomer
(
     intCustomerID INTEGER NOT NULL,
     strCustomerName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     strAddress VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT TCustomer_PK PRIMARY KEY (intCustomerID)
)

CREATE TABLE TCustomerLocation
(
     intLocationID INTEGER NOT NULL,
     intLocationIndex INTEGER NOT NULL,
     intCustomerID INTEGER NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT TCustomerLocation_PK 
         PRIMARY KEY(intLocationID, intLocationIndex)
)

CREATE TABLE TLocation
(
     intLocationID INTEGER NOT NULL,
     strLocationName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     strLocationAddress VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     strLocationCity VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT TLocation_PK PRIMARY KEY(intLocationID)
)

CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddCustomerLocation
     @strCustomerName VARCHAR(50),
     @strAddress VARCHAR(50),
     @strLocationName VARCHAR(50),
     @strLocationAddress VARCHAR(50),
     @strLocationCity VARCHAR(50)
AS

BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET XACT_ABORT ON

DECLARE @intCustomerID INTEGER

SELECT @intCustomerID = MAX(intCustomerID) + 1
FROM TCustomer (TABLOCKX) -- LOCK TABLE UNTIL THE END OF TRANSACTION

SELECT @intCustomerID = COALESCE( @intCustomerID , 1)

    INSERT INTO TCustomer (intCustomerID, strCustomerName , strAddress)
    VALUES(@intCustomerID ,@strCustomerName ,@strAddress)

DECLARE @intLocationID  INTEGER
DECLARE @intLocationIndex   INTEGER

SELECT @intLocationID = MAX(intLocationID) + 1
FROM TLocation (TABLOCKX) -- LOCK TABLE UNTIL THEEND OF TRANSACTION


COMMIT TRANSACTION

GO
```

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I'm going to guess from the `TABLOCKX` hint at the end that it is in fact `sql-server`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a DBA but I wish these ID fields were IDENTITY fields. Anyway I think the select in question would be `SELECT @intLocationIndex = MAX(intLocationIndex) +1 Where intCustomerID = @intCustomerID`